# Add a String as an Item to a tableWidget in QT/Python

Tags: python, string, qt, qtablewidget, qtablewidgetitem

I have an array with strings and I want to add each string in a different row and the same column of a `tableWidget`.

I'm using the function `setItem` to change the desired field, but I get the error `QTableWidget.setItem(int, int, QTableWidgetItem): argument 3 has unexpected type 'str'`.
I've searched a little and I think I have to use the function `QTableWidgetItem` ([here](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qtablewidgetitem.html#QTableWidgetItem-2)) to convert the string into a `tableWidgetItem`, however, I have no idea how to use that function, and what 'type' means (the integer value).

An (concrete) example how to use that function to convert a string into a `tableWidgetItem` would be very helpful.

So far my code looks like this:

```
pc = 2
i = 0
while i <= pc:
    self.tableWidget.insertRow(i)
    self.tableWidget.setItem(i, 0, parameter[i])
    i += 1
```

It would also be helpful if someone points out if there's a better way to add a string to a `tableWidget` than `setItem`.

Answer (score 6):

The [QTableWidgetItem](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/qtablewidgetitem.html#QTableWidgetItem-2) constructor accepts a string as an argument.  In your case, you just need to change your fifth line to (assuming `parameter` is a list of strings)

```
self.tableWidget.setItem(i, 0, QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(parameter[i]))
```

Answer (score 0):

You get the error because setItem takes in QTableWidgetItem* as input for the third argument. Try this

```
pc = 2
self.tableWidget.setRowCount(pc)
i = 0
while i <= pc:
    self.tableWidget.setItem(i, 0, QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(parameter[i]))
    i += 1
```