# PyQt5, QTablewidget.setItem() not working like documented

Tags: python, pyqt5, qtablewidget

when I try to write to a specific cell in an QTablewidget I only got an TypeError, although I follow the documentation.

The [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython-5/PySide2/QtWidgets/QTableWidget.html#PySide2.QtWidgets.PySide2.QtWidgets.QTableWidget.setItem) instructs me:

```py
self.tblLieferboxen.setItem(0,0,'foo')
```

which leads to `TypeError: setItem(self, int, int, QTableWidgetItem): argument 3 has unexpected type 'str'`

Then I assumed that it wanted 'self' passed as the first parameter and did so with

```py
self.tblLieferboxen.setItem(self, 0,0,'foo')
```

but again `TypeError: setItem(self, int, int, QTableWidgetItem): argument 1 has unexpected type 'deckblaetterUi'`.

Then I thought I would be clever and pass the parameters as keyword-args ...

```py
self.tblLieferboxen.setItem(row=0, column=0, item='foo')
```

but it wasn't meant to be ...`TypeError: setItem() takes no keyword arguments`

What am I doing wrong or what have I overlooked to write to a single cell (not a whole row)?

The complete class:

```py
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, uic, QtCore, QtGui

class deckblaetterUi(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(deckblaetterUi, self).__init__()
        uic.loadUi('ui/deckblaetter.ui', self)

        self.rb3040.clicked.connect(self.waehle3040)
        self.rb3030.clicked.connect(self.waehle3030)
        self.rb2121.clicked.connect(self.waehle2121)
        self.rb2121C.clicked.connect(self.waehle2121C)

        self.tblLieferboxen.setItem(0, 0, 'foo')

        self.btnBoxenlabelsErstellen.clicked.connect(self.btnBoxenlabelsErstellenClicked)

        self.show()
```

Comment: The function takes three parameters: 2 ints and a QTableWidgetItem. You seem to be passing a string instead of an QTableWidgetItem object. You should try creating such an object first, and then passing as the third argument to .setItem

Comment: Thank you Peter ... those who can read have a clear advantage. Obviously I do not belong to this species.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you [Peter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10239224/peter).

Same I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7043857/5690568) (before i read your comment).

I did not read the documentation correctly and wrongly assumed that `item` was a string. But it is clearly stated there that `item` must be of type `PySide2.QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem`

With the following code everything runs as it should:

```py
self.tblLieferboxen.setItem(0, 0, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem('foo'))
```